# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :ribbit_id=>"18"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the routes file:

```
resources :ribbits do
  resources :comments
end
```

Here's the comments_controller.rb *edit* action:

```
def edit
  @ribbit = Ribbit.find(params[:ribbit_id])
  @comment = @ribbit.comments.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to @user unless @user == current_user
end
```

And that's the view:

```
<% @ribbit.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class="comment">
    <% comment_user = comment.user%>
    <img src="<%= comment_user.avatar_url unless comment_user.blank?%>">
    <%= comment.user.name if comment.user %>
    <p>
      <%= comment.body if comment %>
    </p>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_ribbit_comment_path(@ribbit, comment) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am getting the error:

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil,
>   :ribbit_id=>"18"} missing required keys: [:id]

Would be grateful for help!

Comment: Please don't change the original context of the question!

Comment: If you changed the question after Pavan answered it, you should accept Pavan's answer and ask a new question.

Comment: @RichPeck, Didn't know that as I'm the first day registered here. Now I am aware of the main rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your Rabbit Controller Action.

In your `Show` action you are creating a new `comment` for `rabit` 
This Newly created Comment is not saved in Database and so does not have an ID yet. So in your view error occurs that there is not any ID for this comment.

I don't know why are you creating this Comment if you need it then you should have a check for `Edit` link that Create a link if record is already created. Because this make no sense to Edit a record which is not created yet.

So this would work

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_ribbit_comment_path(@ribbit, comment) unless comment.new_record?%>
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you for your time to answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil,
>   :ribbit_id=>"18"} missing required keys: [:id]

You need to change

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_ribbit_comment_path(@ribbit) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_ribbit_comment_path(@ribbit, comment) %>
```

Your `route` expects `:id` and `:ribbit_id` as ***required keys***. Since `:id` is ***nil***, so is the error.

Comment: Changed to `edit_ribbit_comment_path(@ribbit, comment)`. I get the same error

Comment: @RomanKanafotskiy, `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_ribbit_comment_path(comment, @ribbit) %>`

Comment: @pavan flip those 2 objects

Comment: @pavan now it gives me this: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :id=>"18", :ribbit_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:ribbit_id]` after I flipped

Comment: @RomanKanafotskiy What is the name of the view file and the action which it is mapped to?

Comment: @Pavan, the view is ribbits/show and it maps to show action of ribbits controller
`def show
     @ribbit = Ribbit.find(params[:id])
     @comment = @ribbit.comments.new
   end`

Comment: @RomanKanafotskiy Do You have any comments associated to that ribbit?

Comment: @Pavan, I do. Here's the git repo, so it will be easier to interact [git](https://github.com/RomanUkraine/reddit-like-app)

Comment: @RomanKanafotskiy If you really have the comments for that ribbit, then my answer should work.